# parsing date string in perl

Tags: perl, datetime, perl-module

I am trying to check whether a variable `$test` contains a valid date format by attempting to parse it with Date::Manip. It works as expected when the format is 'YYYY/MM/DD'. If I change the format to 'DD/MM/YYYY' (my $test="20/4/2012")  it's not working properly. I tried a config function for setting to uk date format but still it didn't work.

```
use Date::Manip qw(ParseDate );
my $test="20_4_2012";
#my $test="2012_4_20";

$test =~ s/_/\//g;

print $test;

$date=ParseDate($test);

if(!$date) {
  print "baddate : $date\n";
}

else {
  print "Guddate: $date\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `Time::ParseDate` which allows you to specify `UK` in it's arguments to the parser function.

```
use Time::ParseDate; 

my $test="20/4/2012";

$time = parsedate($test, UK => 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

What did your config function call look like? I can get your script to work by adding this:

```
Date_Init("DateFormat=non-US");
```

before the ParseDate. (And also adding `Date_Init` to the import list in the `use`)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  Tried  Date_Init("DateFormat=non-US");  it's not working

Comment: Let's break it down to a bare minimum. `perl -MDate::Manip=ParseDate,Date_Init -e 'Date_Init("DateFormat=non-US"); print ParseDate("20/4/2012");'` -- that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you've already found your solution :-)

But for the benefit of anyone passing through looking for some date parsing tools for Perl, I can highly recommend the core module `Time::Piece` -- it's insanely good at working out what you meant from any old date string.

The real answer to your specific question is "it depends what you mean by valid" of course.